# ImageView with squared pixels (without interpolation)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a bitmap of 9X11 pixels representing a maze with the path in green, walls in black, start in orange and blue end.

it matrix is:

```
int[][] map = new int[][] { 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, };
```

The problem is that when I draw the bitmap in a ImageView (fill_parent,fill_parent) the result is:
[image]

How can I keep the pixels squared?

Note: I create the Bitmap with

```
 Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

and set the pixels with the method

```
 bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color.XXX);
```

Comment: One option is to scale your `Bitmap` up using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` and setting `filter` to `false`. Then, you'd have to do this each time after updating your small bitmap, or update the large bitmap directly when setting a new 'pixel' (more like a 'tile' then).

Comment: What happens when you disable antialiasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an image view to scale without antialiasing, what you really need to do is get a BitmapDrawable.  Example:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), bitmap);
bd.setAntiAlias(false);
```

Comment: Anti-aliasing affects the edges of the bitmap only so it applies only when the drawable is rotated and not applied for content.