# Android Studio: Imageview background blurs on larger minimum size than image

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I am working with Imageviews and am using relatively small images(10x16px) for larger image views(100s of px).

Like anyone would do, I set my imageview's minimum height/width as needed

```
Imageview.setMinimumWidth(WIDTH);
Imageview.setMinimumHeight(HEIGHT);
```

However, when I test my program the initial image scales with lots of blur(image is intended to have a pixel style so the blur is really problematic). The resampling is bilinear I assume.

(gives me this kinda look)

[image]

So essentially, is there a way to make the imageview scale the image like this? Nearest Neighbor Resampling

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageView with squared pixels (without interpolation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440934/imageview-with-squared-pixels-without-interpolation)

Comment: was looking at that a while ago but it has a "Bitmap" solution so I'm only going to switch to bitmap as a last resort

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because the `ImageView` has a larger pixel density than the image provided, therefore it has to scale up the image to match the bounds. To avoid this you have two options.

First, you can disable anti-aliasing of the image, which will scale the image without blurring it:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.sprite);
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), bitmap);
drawable.setAntiAlias(false);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Or you can provide an image large enough so that it will only ever be scaled down, not up.

Comment: "new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), bitmap);" confused what to put in the "bitmap" spot

Comment: @Hisownmother Sorry, there are a few ways of obtaining a `Bitmap` from resources as well. I added a simple method to the code above.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with scale type property for image view as FitXY
I guess that will fix your issue

Comment: Will just scale the image to fit the dimensions of the `ImageView`. If the size of the `ImageView` is larger than the image, the image will still blur.