# Android ImageView with PixelArt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

I want to dispaly pixelart in an ImageView but it keeps getting blurry.
I tried it like explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152891/android-studio-imageview-background-blurs-on-larger-minimum-size-than-image) post (and some others) and I tried it with the function createScaledBitmap like you can see in the code. But it still gets blurry.
What else can I do to show my PixelArt correctly?

```
        var bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fu, 120, 120, false)
        var drawable = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, bitmap)
        drawable.setAntiAlias(false)
        drawable.setFilterBitmap(false)
        myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable )
```

(The Imageview is inside a RecyclerView but I don't think that that is important for my problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're scaling the image up before disabling the filtering, so it still looks filtered. It also wastes memory to enlarge a small sprite into a large bitmap.

You don't need to mess with manual scaling like that. You can set the drawable on you ImageView (either assign it in your XML layout or call `setImageResource` on it). Then set `isFilterBitmap` to false on its drawable.

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mySprite) // if not already set in XML
myImageView.drawable?.isFilterBitmap = false
```

Comment: there ist no myImageView.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.mySprite)
but it works with:
myImageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic)
myImageview.drawable.isFilterBitmap = false